# How to display discount percentage if discount percentage is greater than zero? PHP

Tags: php, percentage

I have php script for selling deals. Currently, there are 2 requirements for deal; 1 is deal_value (original price) and special_value (discount price). So i have variables: deal_value, special_value, deal_percentage (which i already coded to get this discount percentage). These are inserted into database already.

So how do i show discount percentage label if the deal percentage > 0%?

FYI: i have this php html hot label already, so how do i code and display this hot_label if deal percentage > 0%?

**Also, i need to echo the whole div= hot_label, which there is php inside and because there is css in this class=hot_label**

```
 <div class="hot_label">
      <p>OFF</p>
      <b><?php echo round($h->deal_percentage); ?>%</b>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are asking how to write a simple [`if` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)?

Comment: Sorry, but because i am a beginning deleloper and i just learned php, so there are confusions when i look at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if ( $h->deal_percentage > 0) {
    echo '<div class="hot_label"><p>OFF</p><b>' . round($h->deal_percentage) . '%</b></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but i need to echo the whole div class="hot_label". Can you help? thanks again

Comment: Using Gortekk answer, is just moving the if to the top, enclosuring the whole content. I made an edit to it, just need to me reviewed.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i tried but it did not work since there is an <?php if ?> within that div.